# FTP file download with Spring-Integration?

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I want to download a file from ftp server periodically (only when the file has changed). Therefore I'd like to use `Spring-Integration` 4.0.

What is the annotation based configuration equivalent of the following setup with `int-ftp`?

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
            channel="ftpChannel"
            session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
            filename-pattern="*.txt"
            auto-create-local-directory="true"
            delete-remote-files="false"
            remote-directory="/">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I started with the following, but don't know how I can configure the channel with its attributes like `session-factory`, `remote-directory` etc.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class Application {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory<FTPFile> sessionFactory() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory ftp = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        ftp.setHost("ftp.test");
        ftp.setPort(21);
        ftp.setUsername("anonymous");
        ftp.setPassword("anonymous");
        return ftp;
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public String connect() {
        // return the ftp file
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel")
    public void foo(String payload) {
        System.out.println("paylod: " + payload);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (S)FTP inbound adapters are on the more complex side; we're working in the DSL to make this easier but, currently, you need an `@Bean FtpInboundFileSynchronizer` wired up with appropriate properties and inject it into

Then

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "ftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
public MessageSource receive() {
    FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(synchronizer());
    ...
    return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer; it's actually a little more efficient to annotate the `MessageSource` @Bean directly.